# How work with Fragment class in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have used Tabbed Activity (HomeActivity) with Top navigation bar, in my Android project. It has three tabs and I have created three Fragments for those tabs. When a fragment is created it automatically adds a Java class to the project folder. Afterwards, I have associated those fragments to each tab of the navigation bar using `onCreateView` method of Activity class (HomeActivity). But when I run my application, even though there are Fragment classes, they won't create objects from those classes.

Following indicates the `onCreateView` method in HomeActivity class.

```
@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==1) {
                Log.i("TEST", "onCreateView method framgnet 1");
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
                return rootView;
            }else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==2) {
                Log.i("TEST", "onCreateView method framgnet 2");
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_transactions, container, false);
                return rootView;
            }else if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==3) {
                Log.i("TEST", "onCreateView method framgnet 3");
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lendings, container, false);
                return rootView;
            }else {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
                return rootView;                                                                            // edit this condition
            }
        }
```

When I created the tabbed activity(HomeActivity), in automatically provided a one activity with just `.xml` file in res folder of project. But it won't provide a Java Fragment class for it. But when I intentionally create other Fragments, both `.xml` and `.java` files are created. Still Java class in not functioning.

This is my `getItem` method in `SectionPageAdapter` (extends FragmentPageAdapter) inner class.

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }
```

Then I changed that method as follows,

```
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
//            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return Transactions.newInstance("" ,"");
                case 1:
                    return Lendings.newInstance("", "");
                case 2:
                    return Home.newInstance("", "");
            }
            return null;
        }
```

I'm new to Android. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
** case 0:
                    return Transactions.newInstance("" ,"");
                case 1:
                    return Lendings.newInstance("", "");
                case 2:
                    return Home.newInstance("", "");
**
```

result getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) = null. And will return

```
** else {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
                return rootView;                                                                            // edit this condition
            }
**
```

Please return Home.newInstance("1", "1"),Lendings.newInstance("2", "2"); Transactions.newInstance("3" ,"3");; //example

```
** case 0:
                        return Transactions.newInstance("1" ,"1");
                    case 1:
                        return Lendings.newInstance("2", "2");
                    case 2:
                        return Home.newInstance("3", "3");
    **
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you did not create 3 object of Fragment. Please show more code.

Comment: case 0:
                    return Transactions.newInstance("" ,"");
                case 1:
                    return Lendings.newInstance("", "");
                case 2:
                    return Home.newInstance("", "");

Answer (score 1):

You understand wrongly on how android process Fragment and Tabbed view.

When you use Tabbed Activity template, it actually `ViewPager` to load 3 Fragments, and these fragments are managed by an `Adapter` (I think by default it's `SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter`)

If you want to create different Fragment with different layout (seperate xml), then you need to make change from that adapter:

```
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a SearchFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return Fragment1.newInstance(position + 1);
            case 1:
                return Fragmen2.newInstance(position + 1);
            case 2:
                return Fragment3.newInstance(position + 1);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thnx. But after I tried this on the getItem method my app stopped working just after it starts. I will update my question with that.